# Extract the largest value for each day from a matrix

Tags: performance, matrix, matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix in which the right-most elements are repeated YYYYMMDD dates in descending order, for example:

```
  40        1122        1711    20160326
 169         700         950    20160326
  40        1630        1711    20160326
 182         700         950    20160327
  40        1029        1711    20160327
 169         700         950    20160327
  40        1630        1711    20160327
 122         700         950    20160328
  40        1630        1711    20160328
 169         700         950    20160328
  40        1630        1711    20160328
3049         700         950    20160331
  40        1630        1711    20160331
3049         700         950    20160331
  40        1630        1711    20160331
 169         700         950    20160401
  40        1630        1711    20160401
 169         700         950    20160401
  40        1630        1711    20160401
```

Within each date, I want to keep only the row that corresponds to the largest element in the leftmost column. So I would like to produce a new matrix:

```
 169         700         950    20160326
 182         700         950    20160327
 169         700         950    20160328
3049         700         950    20160331
 169         700         950    20160401
```

The code I have now is:

```
idx1 = find([1;diff(A(:,4))]);
idx2 = find([diff(A(:,4));1]);
B = zeros(length(idx1),4);
for ii = 1:length(idx1)
    row_number = find(A(idx1(ii):idx2(ii),1) == max(A(idx1(ii):idx2(ii),1)),1);
    B(ii,:) = A(idx1(ii)+row_number-1,:);
end
```

Are there ways to improve this code? I'm looking for coding conventions, improve performance, possible vectorization etc.

Comment: It looks like there are about 4 rows for each date (except the first one, possibly excluded from your copy).  Is this a coincidence, or a usable pattern within the data?

Answer (score 4):

A few notes:  (I implemented this in Octave, so there *may* be differences between my code and a proper Matlab implementation, but there shouldn't be).

1. First we care about only [unique](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) dates, right?  So lets grab
   indices for their groupings.  I'm assuming this original data is
   stored in the matrix `A`.

   ```
   [X, y, z] = unique(A(:, 4))
   ```

   Now `z` is the only value I used from this output, so you could
   ignore the other returns by putting `~` in their place.
2. Second, let's split out data up based on these groups.  We can use
   the function [`accumarray()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to accomplish this nicely.  If we
   pass in the function handle `@max` to it, it'll even find the max
   within these groups.

   ```
   B = accumarray(z, A(:, 1), [], @max)
   ```

   There is some trick to get each row corresponding to that maximum value based on the `z` parameter, but after investigating this for a few hours I still haven't figured it out and have given up.  You could try using `find()` to get these rows instead, using `z` to make sure we are grabbing the right values.

Comment: Nice =) `accumarray` with `@max` was really clever, but man I'm having a hard time trying to get the entire row out! I think I'm giving up too =/ It would be easy if it was only the first and last column, but grabbing those in between was hard. I posted another suggestion with sorting first, followed by unique. =)

Answer (score 1):

**The non-vectorized approach first:**

1. Your code looks pretty good, but you're performing some of the operation multiple times. This won't matter much for small matrices, but it's a good habit to try to avoid such overhead.

   For instance, the two vectors `idx1` and `idx2` could be created like this:

   ```
   ind = find([1;diff(A(:,4));1]);
   idx1 = ind(1:end-1);
   idx2 = ind(2:end)-1;
   ```

   It might look more cumbersome, but it will be a lot faster since there's only one call to `find` and only one call to `diff`.
2. In general, it's better to use [`numel` instead of `length`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119739/difference-between-matlabs-numel-and-length-functions) to find the number of elements in a vector. Not only is it more robust, it's also a lot faster for large vectors.
3. You are not using `i` and `j` as variables. Good!

---

**Vectorization**

You can achieve this quite simply using a combination of [`sortrows`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) and [`unique`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

There is one important thing you should know first: When calling `unique` with two outputs, the first will give you the unique values, while the second output will give you the index of **the last** instance of the element.

You want the row with the largest value in the first column for each unique date. What you can do then is sort the rows of the matrix based on the values in the first column in ascending order. Then, you use `unique` on the last column to find the last instance of each date. Now, you can use the sorted matrix and the indices of the unique dates to find your final output matrix:

```
B = sortrows(A);           % Sort the column based on the values in the first column
[~, ia] = unique(B(:,4));  % Find the last instance of each unique date
B(ia,:)                    % Use those indices in the sorted matrix to get the final output
ans =

        169        700        950   20160326
        182        700        950   20160327
        169        700        950   20160328
       3049        700        950   20160331
        169        700        950   20160401
```